# Resources to learn about the state of academia in the early 1900s?

Tags: scientific-method, academia, science

Was not sure if I could ask this in the Academia Stack Exchange as the question is a little bit meta, so HSM looked like a more appropriate place. Apologies if that's not the case.

There is currently some criticism around the state of academia: too much emphasis on publishing, predatory journals, non competitive pay, very competitive environment, and crisis of replication, among others.

I'm wondering if anyone could point me to resources where I could get a view of how the academic environment was in the early 1900s, how different the environment was when degrees were more of a "premium" than they are today and maybe different issues affecting research back then.

Comment: Geographical area? Particular area of study? This is really really broad...